# Azure SQL Database v12 - Full-text query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, full-text-search, azure-sql-database

We are using: Azure SQL Database v12 (Standard S3) - ASP.NET WEB APP

We are encountering an error when we run a stored procedure that includes a full-text search. The error is:

> An error has occurred during the **full-text query**. Common causes include: word-breaking errors or timeout, FDHOST permissions/ACL issues, service account missing privileges, malfunctioning IFilters, communication channel issues with FDHost and sqlservr.exe, etc

This error occurs during the first attempt to run the stored procedure ONLY. If we refresh the page after the error has occurred the stored procedure runs (extremely fast) as it should without any problem.

One of the articles that we red suggests to execute the `sp_fulltext_service` and set `verify_signature` to 0. We haven't managed to do so with SQL DB v12. We got an error: DBCC command `CALLFULLTEXT` is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You should retry on the error. This happens when Fdhost process is not paired with SQL (after a failover for example) and when query runs it might have tried connecting and it timed out. On the retry it will succeed and should run without any issues.

Thanks,

Mihaela

Answer (score 0):

please email me [snarlap at microsoft dot com] your server and database name if you encounter the issue frequently. All the word breaker dlls are shipped and signed by Microsoft and SQL DB doesn't allow third party word breakers. So setting verify_signature has no impact. Also SQL DB team amanges full text settings according to the database edition and DTU so these options are no available in SQL DB